# Return the sum of elements in an array while ignoring all elements that lie in between elements 6 and 9 (also included)

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

This is the whole question:

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 9 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 9). Return 0 for no numbers.

Examples of what the output should look like are:

```
summer_69([1, 3, 5]) --> 9
summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) --> 9
summer_69([2, 1, 6, 9, 11]) --> 14
```

I have tried to use my own method even though there are other solutions available but I wanted to know why my solution was giving an error.
I have tried to initialize a separate list called **arr1** and I intend to iterate through the given array until it reaches the first 6. Then I want to keep adding the elements after that 6 into the new array **arr1** until the iterator reaches a 9. And as for the rest of the numbers I sum them up in the **else** block of the code.

Here's my solution:

```
def summer_69(arr):
    sum = 0
    arr1 =[]
    for x,i in enumerate(arr):
        if i == 6:
            while arr[x]!=9:
                arr1 = i
                x+=1
        else:
            sum += arr[i]
    return sum
```

I get the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone point out why it's giving me that error?

Comment: instead of sum += arr[i], use sum += arr[x], you will not get IndexError: list index out of range, but result sum be wrong with this logic

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iterator solution (I love those):

```
def summer_69(arr):
    it = iter(arr)
    return sum(x for x in it if x != 6 or 9 not in it)
```

This mainly sums the values. And whenever `6` is encountered, the `9 not in it` consumes all values until the next `9` (and it's false, so none of the values from that `6` to that `9` make it into the sum).

Comment: This is the shortest solution I've seen. Thank you.

Comment: @versacecrispies Btw, is that problem online somewhere? I always like to submit solutions where the problem came from to get some extra verification. For example all three of the shown examples can also be correctly solved with `sum(x for x in arr if not 6 <= x <= 9)` (and a now deleted answer did that), but I'd expect it to fail on the whole test suite.

Comment: @HeapOverflow can you please explain how 'if x != 6 or 9 not in it' is working ?

Comment: @pk786 If x isn't 6, it's included in the sum. If it *is* 6, then `9 not in it` consumes everything until the next 9 (and it's false, so none of it gets into the sum).

Comment: @HeapOverflow yes I'm taking a course on Udemy for Python and this was a question asked in one of the videos. The curator's solution was different so that's why I wanted to check why mine wasn't working. And I didn't see the deleted answer but why do you think it'd fail, though?

Comment: @versacecrispies For example for `[6, 1, 9]` it computes 1, even though the 1 is between the 6 and 9.

Comment: @HeapOverflow that's what I want to understand how '9 not in it' is consuming everything till 9

Comment: Not sure but I think it's because the element at the first index is 6 and the rest of the examples don't have it as the element at the first index.

Comment: @pk786 Well, in order to find out whether there's a 9 in there, it needs to go through it until it finds one (or until the end, but the problem guarantees that there is one).

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this line:

```
    sum += arr[i]
```

you are passing the value that should be an index. Just change *i* to *x*

CODE:

```
def summer_69(arr):
    sum = 0
    arr1 =[]
    for x, i in enumerate(arr):
        if i == 6:
            while arr[x]!=9:
                arr1 = i
                x += 1
        else:
            sum += arr[x]
    return sum
```

*NOTE:

You need to better name your variables. For example here in your code:

```
for x, i in enumerate(arr):
```

Should be:

```
for index, value in enumerate(arr):
```

So you can read or debug better for errors.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I changed the values but I'm not getting the correct answers for the second and third array examples mentioned in the question. It gives me 33 and 23 respectively as the answers. Can't figure it out.

Comment: Change your if-else statement with this
    `if i < 6 or i >9:
         sum += arr[x]`

Comment: No problem, mate.